# Updating the type attribute of all CSS and JS references in the HEAD

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I created a new theme in Magento 2 extending the default Magento Luma theme.

However, now I want to make some very specific customizations to all CSS and JS files referenced in the `<HEAD>`.

I want to change all CSS references that look like this:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="all" href="https://my-magento-url/pub/static/version1574090503/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
```

to look like this:

```
<link  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css/custom"  media="all" href="https://my-magento-url/pub/static/version1574090503/frontend/restive/magedot/en_US/mage/calendar.css" />
```

and all JS references that look like this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript"  src="https://my-magento-url/pub/static/version1573830556/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

to look like this:

```
<script  type="text/javascript/custom"  src="https://my-magento-url/pub/static/version1573830556/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

Notice that the `type` attribute changes from `text/{file_type}` to `text/{file_type}/custom`, where `{file_type}` is either `css` or `javascript`.

What files need to be updated/extended to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

for values allowed for the type attribute check [this](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), but why do you want this change for css/js files?

Comment: Thanks. I know what I am inputing are not valid types. I have some additional functionality that will leverage that.

Comment: Try this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css